# Laravel orderby with relationship

Tags: php, laravel

i'm trying to sort the student list by each level with using relationship method with OrderBy function but unfortunately i can't make it work any idea whats missing on my code?

**Note:**
every-time i remove the orderby my code will work but students level are not arrange accordingly

**Controller:**

```
$students=Student::with('level')->where(['status' => 'ENROLLED'])->get()->orderBy('level_name','asc');
```

**View**

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
        </tr>
         @foreach($students as $std)
        <tr>

              <td>
                    {{$std->student_name}}

              </td>  
             <td>
                 @foreach($std->level as $lv)
                   {{$lv->level_name}}
                 @endforeach
             </td>

        </tr>
         @endforeach
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't order by a relationship because under the hood laravel makes two seperate queries under the hood.

You can instead use a `join`, something like this (beware I guessed your table names, so you may have to update them).

```php
$users = Student::join('levels', 'students.level_id', '=', 'levels.id')
  ->orderBy('levels. level_name', 'asc')->select('students.*')->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**Controller:**

```php
$students = Student::with(['level' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->orderBy('level_name', 'asc');
}])->where(['status' => 'ENROLLED'])->get();
```

In addition you can add `orderBy()` to relation method.

**Student Model:**

```php
public function level()
{
    return $this->relationMethod(Level::class)->orderBy('level_name', 'asc');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$students=Student::with('level')->where(['status' => 'ENROLLED'])->orderBy('level_name','asc')->get();
```